# Theme my login different templates for profile and login

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins

How can i apply two different templates to the profile page and the login page? I am using theme my login plugin for wordpress.

The problem is that be it login or profile, the plugin takes the user to the same page. although it does have the ability to change the urls but actually the login and the profile page are shown on the same page and i cant apply two different templates to same page obviously.

Being on same wordpress page how can i apply two different templates to them? Can I create a page just for profile-form and assign it a different template and show it?

Any kind of workaround is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First create a new template and name it your-template.php place this file in your theme's root directory. At the top of that page wrtie

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: your-template-name
*/
?>
```

save the file.
Create a new page in wordpress and apply this new template to that page at the bottom right you will find the option. You can write custom HTML in that page.
If you want to create php page then I suggest copy the login page and give it a name like home.php or profile.php and then apply your-template to that page and redirect the users to that page after login. Hope this would be helpful.